# How to change IE to Chrome?

Tags: html, vba, autocomplete

I need to change it to Chrome which I tried to do but failed. Need to make this code as long:

```
IE.Document.All("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTID").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a4")
```

This is my entire code details to understand

```
Function FillInternetForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'create new instance of IE. use reference to return current open IE if
'you want to use open IE window. Easiest way I know of is via title bar.
IE.Navigate "https://mms.hitachi-payments.com/prizmmms"
'go to web page listed inside quotes
      IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy
DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend
IE.Document.All("userName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b1")
IE.Document.All("PassWord").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("d1")
IE.Document.All("imgSubmit").Click
IE.Document.All("ct100_call").Click 'this is menu
IE.Document.All("callSupport").Click 'this is sub menu
IE.Document.All("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTID").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a4")
```

Below this new window will popup then it should select "link_code" from that window

```
IE.Document.All("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnTID1").click 'after clicking this new window will come 

End Function
```

Comment: The reason why you're interacting that easily with Internet Explorer is because Internet Explorer is an application sharing the same Object Model than Microsoft Excel / VBA. Google Chrome is an external application, I'm not sure it provides APIs to VBA as rich as Internet Explorer does. However, if you want a point to get started, google "Google Chrome API for VBA"

Comment: thanks...can you help me out for 2nd point